# Downloading images only once from different urls and storing in sdcard in android

Tags: android

I have a requirement where I need to parse the  tag in a response xml, store it in sdcard and retrieve every time I need to use it.

I want to download only once just like Whatsapp and store in sdcard. So that next time, I scan the sdcard first and then download if necessary, I tried the lazylist program but it just downloads and loads the list directly.

NOTE : Each image I am getting from different URL. I am parsing it and am saving it in an array. How do I save the images from different urls in sdcard and download only once

Answer (score 2):

in Lazy Loading implementation of ImageLoader class, on thread's stop method all image files are being deleted, check if you are implementing same implementation, if yes, then remove code, which is deleting files.

If you are not using file storage at all to cache images, then see example:

http://code.google.com/p/shelves/source/browse/trunk/Shelves/?r=19

Answer (score 2):

As you mentioned in your question. You have a arrayList of the Images url which you are getting from the response xml.

And now you want to download that images from those URL and then want to save in sd-card.

So follow below steps

1. Create a AsyncTask for download Images from the server.
   Pass the arrayList to the AsyncTask and download all the images
   Set the download image path to the sd-card as you want to save in the sd-card.
2. Create a database or use the Preference to keep the track of the files which are downloaded so that next time you can be able to find how many image you still have to download and which are already downloaded.
3. When you display images in the activity then first check the sd-card. If you find all the images from the sd-card then no need to download it again and if any images is still not downloaded then download it again.